# I want to add a subquery with a date parameter to return a calculated value but my query is not working

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a query that fetches data from oracle inventory and purchasing. Now I want to add a subquery from po_line_locations_all with a date parameter to return a calculated value as if the value lies in the subquery show it else display zero, But in my case the query shows nothing if subquery returns null.

I want to show the result of the main query even if subquery returns null.

```
SELECT distinct msib.segment1          Item_Code,
               MSIB.inventory_item_id,
               MSIB.organization_id   ORG_ID,

               msib.description             Item_Description,
               msib.primary_unit_of_measure UOM,
               ph.attribute1                Item_Type,
               SUM(plla.quantity) - SUM(plla.quantity_received) On_Order,
               ph.currency_code currency,
               max(pl.unit_price) FOB_Value_in_FCY,
               max(ph.rate_date),
               max(ph.rate) forex_rate,
               (
               SELECT  SUM (moq.transaction_quantity)
               FROM mtl_system_items_b msi, mtl_onhand_quantities moq
               WHERE moq.organization_id(+) = msi.organization_id
               AND moq.inventory_item_id(+) = msi.inventory_item_id
               and moq.ORGANIZATION_ID =MSIB.organization_id
               and msi.inventory_item_id = MSIB.inventory_item_id 
               GROUP BY msi.segment1, msi.organization_id
                ) CURR_STOCK,
               (
               SELECT NVL(ABS(sum(mtmt.transaction_quantity)),0) from MTL_MATERIAL_TRANSACTIONS mtmt 
               WHERE 1=1
               AND mtmt.inventory_item_id = MSIB.inventory_item_id --4018
               AND mtmt.organization_id = MSIB.organization_id--499
               and mtmt.TRANSACTION_ACTION_ID NOT IN (24, 30)
               AND to_date(mtmt.transaction_date) >= to_date(&Roll_back_date,'DD-MON-RRRR')
               )RB_TRANSACTIONS,
               (
               select ABS(SUM(mmt.transaction_quantity))
               from MTL_MATERIAL_TRANSACTIONS mmt
               where mmt.TRANSACTION_ACTION_ID NOT IN (24, 30)
               and (mmt.ORGANIZATION_ID = MSIB.organization_id --499--579
                   )
               and (mmt.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = MSIB.inventory_item_id --4128 --4165 
                    and mmt.TRANSACTION_TYPE_ID in (33, 52)
                    )
               and (mmt.transaction_date between
                    to_date(add_months(&CONS_f_DATE, -12),'DD-MON-YYYY') 
                    AND to_date(&CONS_f_DATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY')
                    )
                AND (mmt.parent_transaction_id IS NULL)
                       ) annual_Consumption,
                (
                select ABS(SUM(mmt.transaction_quantity) / 4)
                FROM MTL_MATERIAL_TRANSACTIONS mmt
                WHERE mmt.TRANSACTION_ACTION_ID NOT IN (24, 30)
                and (mmt.ORGANIZATION_ID = MSIB.organization_id --499--579
                       )
                and (mmt.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = MSIB.inventory_item_id --4128 --4165 
                AND mmt.TRANSACTION_TYPE_ID in (33, 52)
                )   
                and (mmt.transaction_date between
                                to_date(add_months(&CONS_f_DATE, -12),
                                         'DD-MON-YYYY') AND
                                to_date(&CONS_f_DATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY')) 
                   AND (mmt.parent_transaction_id IS NULL)
                ) months_Consumption,
                (
                select ABS((SUM(mmt.transaction_quantity) / 4) / 3)
                FROM MTL_MATERIAL_TRANSACTIONS mmt
                WHERE mmt.TRANSACTION_ACTION_ID NOT IN (24, 30)
                and (mmt.ORGANIZATION_ID = MSIB.organization_id --499--579
                       )
                and (mmt.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = MSIB.inventory_item_id --4128 --4165 
                     AND mmt.TRANSACTION_TYPE_ID in (33, 52))
                   and (mmt.transaction_date between
                                to_date(add_months(&CONS_f_DATE, -12),
                                         'DD-MON-YYYY') AND
                                to_date(&CONS_f_DATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY')) 
                   AND (mmt.parent_transaction_id IS NULL)
                ) monthly_Average,
                 (
                 select MATERIAL_COST
                   FROM CST_ITEM_COST_TYPE_V vw
                  WHERE vw.organization_id = MSIB.organization_id
                    AND - 1 = -1
                    and (vw.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = MSIB.inventory_item_id)
                    ) Unit_Cost, --new
                    sum(quan.t_quantity) - sum(r_quantity) finala


FROM mtl_system_items_b    MSIB, 
               PO_HEADERS_ALL        ph,
               Po_Lines_All          pl,
               PO_LINE_LOCATIONS_ALL PLLA,
-------------------SUBQUERY---------------------------------------
               (select nvl(sum(subplla.quantity),0) t_quantity, nvl(sum(subplla.quantity_received),0) r_quantity ,subpl.item_id

          from po_headers_all        subph,
               po_lines_all          subpl,
               po_line_locations_all subplla
         where subph.po_header_id = subpl.po_header_id
           and subplla.po_header_id = subph.po_header_id
           and subpl.po_line_id = subplla.po_line_id
           and subplla.org_id = subpl.org_id  
           and to_date(subplla.creation_date) >= to_date(&Roll_back_date,'DD-MON-RRRR')
         group by subph.attribute1, subph.currency_code, subpl.item_id       
         ) quan
-------------------SUBQUERY---------------------------------------


               WHERE 1=1
               and ph.po_header_id = pl.po_header_id
               and msib.inventory_item_id (+) = pl.item_id
               and pl.item_id (+) = quan.item_id
               and plla.po_header_id = ph.po_header_id
               and pl.po_line_id = plla.po_line_id
               and plla.org_id = pl.org_id

               and msib.organization_id in
                   (select haou.organization_id
                   from hr_organization_information hoi,
                   hr_all_organization_units   haou
                   where haou.organization_id = hoi.organization_id
                   and hoi.org_information1 = 'INV'
                   and hoi.org_information2 = 'Y'
                   and haou.name like '%HEIS%')

              and MSIB.Inventory_Item_Id=NVL(&ITEM,MSIB.Inventory_Item_Id)
              and MSIB.organization_id = nvl(&P_ORGI, MSIB.organization_id)
              AND to_date(plla.creation_date) BETWEEN
                  to_date(add_months(&Roll_back_date, -12),'DD-MON-YYYY') AND
                  to_date(&Roll_back_date,'DD-MON-YYYY')

GROUP BY  msib.segment1,
                  MSIB.inventory_item_id,
                  msib.description,
                  MSIB.organization_id,
                  msib.primary_unit_of_measure,
                  ph.attribute1, 
                  ph.currency_code
```

Comment: Why are you not using JOINs introduced with the SQL-92 standard? That's 27 years ago.

Comment: That's a lot of SQL. Consider simplifying to the code to the shortest snippet that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Sql keywords should be all upper or all lower, writing like that is such a bad habit.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your problem is simply using old-syntax joins instead of something that has been around for a really long time.

```
SELECT DISTINCT msib.segment1 Item_Code,
    MSIB.inventory_item_id,
    MSIB.organization_id ORG_ID,
    msib.description Item_Description,
    msib.primary_unit_of_measure UOM,
    ph.attribute1 Item_Type,
    SUM(plla.quantity) - SUM(plla.quantity_received) On_Order,
    ph.currency_code currency,
    max(pl.unit_price) FOB_Value_in_FCY,
    max(ph.rate_date),
    max(ph.rate) forex_rate,
    (
        SELECT SUM(moq.transaction_quantity)
        FROM mtl_system_items_b msi
        RIGHT JOIN mtl_onhand_quantities moq ON moq.organization_id = msi.organization_id
                                            AND moq.inventory_item_id = msi.inventory_item_id
        WHERE moq.ORGANIZATION_ID = MSIB.organization_id
            AND msi.inventory_item_id = MSIB.inventory_item_id
        GROUP BY msi.segment1,
            msi.organization_id
        ) CURR_STOCK,
    (
        SELECT NVL(ABS(sum(mtmt.transaction_quantity)), 0)
        FROM MTL_MATERIAL_TRANSACTIONS mtmt
        WHERE 1 = 1
            AND mtmt.inventory_item_id = MSIB.inventory_item_id --4018
            AND mtmt.organization_id = MSIB.organization_id --499
            AND mtmt.TRANSACTION_ACTION_ID NOT IN (24,30)
            AND to_date(mtmt.transaction_date) >= to_date(&Roll_back_date, 'DD-MON-RRRR')
        ) RB_TRANSACTIONS,
    mmt.annual_Consumption annual_Consumption,
    mmt.annual_Consumption / 4 months_Consumption,
    mmt.annual_Consumption / 12 monthly_Average,
    (
        SELECT MATERIAL_COST
        FROM CST_ITEM_COST_TYPE_V vw
        WHERE vw.organization_id = MSIB.organization_id
          AND vw.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = MSIB.inventory_item_id
        ) Unit_Cost, --new
    sum(quan.t_quantity) - sum(r_quantity) finala
FROM mtl_system_items_b MSIB
LEFT  JOIN PO_HEADERS_ALL ph ON msib.inventory_item_id = pl.item_id
INNER JOIN Po_Lines_All pl ON ph.po_header_id = pl.po_header_id
INNER JOIN PO_LINE_LOCATIONS_ALL PLLA ON plla.po_header_id = ph.po_header_id AND pl.po_line_id = plla.po_line_id AND plla.org_id = pl.org_id
LEFT  JOIN 
    -------------------SUBQUERY---------------------------------------
    (
        SELECT nvl(sum(subplla.quantity), 0) t_quantity,
            nvl(sum(subplla.quantity_received), 0) r_quantity,
            subpl.item_id
        FROM po_headers_all subph 
        INNER JOIN po_lines_all subpl ON subph.po_header_id = subpl.po_header_id
        INNER JOIN po_line_locations_all subplla ON subplla.po_header_id = subph.po_header_id
                                                AND subpl.po_line_id = subplla.po_line_id
                                                AND subplla.org_id = subpl.org_id
        WHERE to_date(subplla.creation_date) >= to_date(&Roll_back_date, 'DD-MON-RRRR')
        GROUP BY subph.attribute1,
            subph.currency_code,
            subpl.item_id
        ) quan ON pl.item_id = quan.item_id
-------------------SUBQUERY---------------------------------------
LEFT JOIN   (
        SELECT mmt.ORGANIZATION_ID,
               mmt.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID,
               ABS(SUM(mmt.transaction_quantity)) AS annual_Consumption
        FROM MTL_MATERIAL_TRANSACTIONS mmt
        WHERE mmt.TRANSACTION_ACTION_ID NOT IN (24,30)
            AND mmt.TRANSACTION_TYPE_ID IN (33,52)
            AND mmt.transaction_date BETWEEN to_date(add_months(&CONS_f_DATE, - 12), 'DD-MON-YYYY')
                                         AND to_date(&CONS_f_DATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY')
            AND mmt.parent_transaction_id IS NULL
        ) mmt ON mmt.ORGANIZATION_ID = MSIB.organization_id --499--579
             AND mmt.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = MSIB.inventory_item_id --4128 --4165 
WHERE msib.organization_id IN (
        SELECT haou.organization_id
        FROM hr_organization_information hoi
        JOIN hr_all_organization_units haou ON haou.organization_id = hoi.organization_id
        WHERE hoi.org_information1 = 'INV'
            AND hoi.org_information2 = 'Y'
            AND haou.name LIKE '%HEIS%'
        )
    AND MSIB.Inventory_Item_Id = NVL(&ITEM, MSIB.Inventory_Item_Id)
    AND MSIB.organization_id = nvl(&P_ORGI, MSIB.organization_id)
    AND to_date(plla.creation_date) BETWEEN to_date(add_months(&Roll_back_date, - 12), 'DD-MON-YYYY')
        AND to_date(&Roll_back_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY')
GROUP BY msib.segment1,
    MSIB.inventory_item_id,
    msib.description,
    MSIB.organization_id,
    msib.primary_unit_of_measure,
    ph.attribute1,
    ph.currency_code;
```

Comment: @andomar 
Here is the query in its simplest form,
The main query is working good without the subquery.
But when subquery returns null (i.e. no output in the date range) the whole query returns nothing.

I want it to display results regardless the subquery results.
My guess is something is wrong with the JOIN

Comment: I have tried the new joins too but still nothing useful

Comment: The subquery wouldn't prevent the rest of the query to return results. There might be something else happening in there.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query in its simplest form, The main query is working good without the subquery. But when subquery returns null (i.e. no output in the date range) the whole query returns nothing. I want it to display results regardless the subquery results. My guess is something is wrong with the JOIN –

```
       SELECT distinct msib.segment1          Item_Code,
               MSIB.inventory_item_id,
               MSIB.organization_id   ORG_ID,

               msib.description             Item_Description,
               msib.primary_unit_of_measure UOM,
               ph.attribute1                Item_Type,
               ph.currency_code currency,
               max(pl.unit_price) FOB_Value_in_FCY,
               max(ph.rate_date),
               max(ph.rate) forex_rate,

                    sum(quan.t_quantity) - sum(r_quantity) finala


FROM mtl_system_items_b    MSIB, 
               PO_HEADERS_ALL        ph,
               Po_Lines_All          pl,
               PO_LINE_LOCATIONS_ALL PLLA,

               ------------SUBQUERY-------------------------------
               (select nvl(sum(subplla.quantity),0) t_quantity, nvl(sum(subplla.quantity_received),0) r_quantity ,subpl.item_id

          from po_headers_all        subph,
               po_lines_all          subpl,
               po_line_locations_all subplla
         where subph.po_header_id = subpl.po_header_id
           and subplla.po_header_id = subph.po_header_id
           and subpl.po_line_id = subplla.po_line_id
           and subplla.org_id = subpl.org_id  
           and to_date(subplla.creation_date) >= to_date(&Roll_back_date,'DD-MON-RRRR')
         group by subph.attribute1, subph.currency_code, subpl.item_id       
         ) quan
          ------------SUBQUERY-------------------------------     
               WHERE 1=1
               and ph.po_header_id = pl.po_header_id
               and msib.inventory_item_id (+) = pl.item_id
               -----------------joining subquery-------------------
               and pl.item_id (+) = quan.item_id
               -----------------joining subquery-------------------
               and plla.po_header_id = ph.po_header_id
               and pl.po_line_id = plla.po_line_id
               and plla.org_id = pl.org_id

               and msib.organization_id in
                   (select haou.organization_id
                   from hr_organization_information hoi,
                   hr_all_organization_units   haou
                   where haou.organization_id = hoi.organization_id
                   and hoi.org_information1 = 'INV'
                   and hoi.org_information2 = 'Y'
                   and haou.name like '%HEIS%')

              and MSIB.Inventory_Item_Id=NVL(&ITEM,MSIB.Inventory_Item_Id)
              and MSIB.organization_id = nvl(&P_ORGI, MSIB.organization_id)
              AND to_date(plla.creation_date) BETWEEN
                  to_date(add_months(&Roll_back_date, -12),'DD-MON-YYYY') AND
                  to_date(&Roll_back_date,'DD-MON-YYYY')

GROUP BY  msib.segment1,
                  MSIB.inventory_item_id,
                  msib.description,
                  MSIB.organization_id,
                  msib.primary_unit_of_measure,
                  ph.attribute1, 
                  ph.currency_code
```